# Mysql regex replace field in serialised array

Tags: mysql, regex, serialization

I have a process (script) to sanitise data from production server so that we can use it on staging and development environments.

The sanitisation process mostly involves removing user identifiable data and elements that are specific to a production environment.

There is a google analytics code stored in a field. The field contains a serialised array, the GA code is stored in one field of the array. I want to remove this with regex. What's the best way to replace the 'lots of text' value based on 'domain_custom_analytics'.

This is essentially the string. I concatinated

a:57:{s:11:"admin_theme";s:23:"domain_custom_analytics";s:XX:"lost of text";}

edit: it would be good to just run the regex command through SQL as it applies to multiple rows

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/aT0pE5/1 ?????????????

Comment: It's not advisable to tamper with serialised data using a regular expression. Unserialise it, remove the data and then serialise it again.

Comment: vks, can I be more targeted in the express to only take the text out after 'domain_custom_analytics'?